# How to handle segmentation fault: 11 c++ osx

Tags: c++, macos

I'm a beginner in programming, and I've come across an error for which I can't find explanation. I have searched thoroughly for a solution, I see many people get this problem, but I haven't been able to fix it.

My program is just about creating a double-type matrix which I fill with two nested loops. After I compile it I get the .exe file, but when I run it the terminal says segmentation fault: 11 logout.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
        long N,NN = 0;
        double h, tau, T1, T2 = 0; 
        N=100;
        NN=pow(N,3);
        h=1/N;
        tau=pow(1/N,3);
        T1=1;
        T2=1.5;
        double T [N][NN];

         for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {              
                 T [i][0]=T1;
                 for (int j=0; j<NN; j++) {
                       T [0][j]=T1;
                       T [N][j]=T2;}}

        for (int i=1; i<N-1; i++) {
                for (int j=1; j<NN; j++) {
                      T [i][j]=T [i][j-1]+(tau/(pow(h,2)))*(T [i+1][j-1]+T [i-1][j-1]-2*T [i][j-1]);}}


return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? Setting lower N does not help. I think this is a very basic program, sorry to bother you all, thank you!

Comment: You are trying to allocate a huge array (about 800 MB) on the stack, so you're getting a classic [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Not valid C++ code. And yet more unreadable math code.

Comment: Hint: `std::vector` and not this.

Comment: Neil Butterworth, what do you mean with unreadable math code? It's just a simple second order Euler numerical scheme for heat equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you are trying to allocate is too large to be done on the stack and you're getting a stack overflow. 
To fix this you can use:

```
double (*T)[NN] = new double[N][NN];
```

to declare your array.